# Async POST python request on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request

I'm working on a python project on Google App Engine and I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) to send push notifications.
Eyerything is working fine but I noticed some lag when I have to send multiple notifications to different devices given by `POST` rest request to Parse server.

To be clearer:

I have a loop with N elements, for every element I have to send a push notifications and so I have to make a POST request to Parse and every connection (of course) take about 300msec to be completed, so it is quite slow to complete entire loop.

I think should be better to change the request in async request but after searching on documentation and on Google I found no clear example how doing it with `urllib2` or `urlfetch` and how pass headers with Parse Key and Applicaton Id..

Working (not async) code is

```
    parse_connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    parse_connection.connect()
    parse_app_id = parse_settings.APPLICATION_ID
    parse_rest_api_key = parse_settings.REST_API_KEY
    parse_connection.request('POST', '/1/push',
                            json.dumps({
                                "channels": ["blabla"],
                                "data": {
                                    "alert": "A",
                                    "title":"B",
                                    "badge": "Increment",
                                    "category": "C",
                                    "sound": "default",
                                    "additionalInfos": {"X": "Custom dict"}}
                            }),
                            {
                                "X-Parse-Application-Id": parse_app_id,
                                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": parse_rest_api_key,
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            })
    return json.loads(parse_connection.getresponse().read())
```

To make it async I think I should use `urlfetch` with

```
    rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc()
    options = json.dumps({"channels": ["blabla"],
                          "data": {
                              "alert": "A",
                              "title": "B",
                              "badge": "Increment",
                              "category": "C",
                              "sound": "default",
                              "additionalInfos": {"X": "Custom dict"}},
                          })
    urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc, "https://api.parse.com/1/push:443", options)
```

But I cannot find examples how adding header..any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     rpc = urlfetch.create_rpc(deadline=60)
     url =  "https://api.parse.com/1/push:443"
     request_params = {
                         "channels": ["blabla"],
                         "data": {
                         "alert": "A",
                         "title":"B",
                         "badge": "Increment",
                         "category": "C",
                         "sound": "default",
                         "additionalInfos": {"X": "Custom dict"}}
                       }
     headers = {
                  "X-Parse-Application-Id": parse_app_id,
                  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": parse_rest_api_key,
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
     urlfetch.make_fetch_call(rpc,
                              url,
                              payload=json.dumps(request_params),
                              method=urlfetch.POST,
                              headers=headers)
```

You can always Look into the [source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/urlfetch#make_fetch_call) if you need more help